# How to simplify matrix / vector expression

Tags: matrices, vectors

I have this expression here,

$ ( -A^{-1}b )^{T} A ( -A^{-1}b) + 2b^{T} ( -A^{-1}b) +c  $

A is a negative definite symmetric matrix, b is a vector in R^n and is constant and c is a real constant.

Am not sure how to simplify this, and also does $ A^{-1} = A^{T} ?  $ if the matrix is symmetric ?

the answer is  $ c -  b^{T}A^{-1}b$  but I am not sure how to get this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily $A^T = A^{-1}$ if the matrix is symmetric.

Use the following properties:

$$
(AB)^T = B^T A^T
$$

$$
AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I
$$

The first property holds even if $A$ or $B$ are one lined matrices, a.k.a. *vectors*. It just needs the product to be well defined.

Comment: How would I simplify  $ (A^{-1})^{T} $

Comment: HINT: $(A^{-1})^T = (A^T)^{-1}$, a consequence of the properties that I wrote in my answer :)